# Chronos does not run job

Tags: docker, mesos, mesosphere

I have set up Mesos Cluster including Marathon & Chronos using Docker image for each service.

Docker images I am using are as follows;

- ZooKeeper: [jplock/zookeeper:3.4.5](https://registry.hub.docker.com/u/jplock/zookeeper/)
- Mesos Master: [redjack/mesos-master:0.21.0](https://registry.hub.docker.com/u/redjack/mesos-master/)
- Mesos Slave: [redjack/mesos-slave:0.21.0](https://registry.hub.docker.com/u/redjack/mesos-slave/)
- Marathon: [mesosphere/marathon:v0.8.2-RC3](https://registry.hub.docker.com/u/mesosphere/marathon/)
- **Chronos**: [tomaskral/chronos:2.3.0-mesos0.21.0](https://registry.hub.docker.com/u/tomaskral/chronos/)

ZooKeeper is running on port 2181, Mesos Master on 5050, Mesos Slave on 5051, marathon on 8088, and Chronos on 8080.

**What I want to do is; Run Docker container on Marathon & Chronos.**

Marathon successfully runs Docker containers as its Apps.

But **Chronos doesn't runs any Jobs.** Even if the Job is not with Docker.

Config for Chronos Job I tried to launch is;

```
{
    "schedule": "R/2015-05-28T10:16:30Z/PT2M",
    "name": "simplejob",
    "cpus": "0.5",
    "mem": "512",
    "command": "while sleep 10; do date -u %T; done"
}
```

Jobs are registered on Chronos but never be launched.
[image]

My command for running Chronos container is as follows;

```
docker run -p 8080:8080 -e LIBPROCESS_PORT=5050 tomaskral/chronos:2.3.0-mesos0.21.0 --http_port 8080 --master zk://<master-hostname>:2181/mesos --zk_hosts zk://<master-hostname>:2181/mesos
```

Comment: Can you share your working Marathon application configuration?

Comment: Also worth double checking that Chronos is registered correctly with Mesos. Does it show up on the frameworks page of the Mesos UI?

Comment: Have you tried the Mesosphere Chronos Docker image? https://registry.hub.docker.com/u/mesosphere/chronos/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change `--zk_hosts zk://<master-hostname>:2181/mesos` in your Chronos command-line to `--zk_hosts <master-hostname>:2181`, since this is supposed to be a list of zk node:port pairs, so that Chronos can store its own state in a `/chronos` znode (as opposed to the `/mesos` znode, where Mesos stores its leading master info).